# Basic Web Development adding selected Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently doing a Web Dev assignment, wanted to have my navbar a different color for the set page so that it does not change when clicked but the page loads. Not sure how to change this, hopefully there is someone to help me out, looking for a quick answer because it is for a assingment.

Thanks in advance!

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    /* Style the header */
    .header {
      background-color: #6699cc;
      padding: 20px;
      color: #e6e6e6;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Style the top navigation bar */
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      color: #993333;
    }
    
    /* When the nav bar is selected */
    .topnav
     {
      color: white;
      background-color: chartreuse;
    }
    .nav-item > a:hover {
      color: aqua;
    }
    
    
    /* Style the topnav links */
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    /* Change color on hover */
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
```

```html
            <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <title>Page 1</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
    
    
    <style></style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
      <a href="#">Page 2</a>
      <a href="#">Page 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    
    
    
       </style>
        </head>
        <body>
     <p>Select what background you'd like to use here!</p>
         <button id="aqua">Dark Cyan</button>
            <button id="green">Green</button>
            <button id="slate_gray">Slate Gray</button>
            <button id="reset">Reset</button>
            <script>
                document.querySelector('#aqua').onclick = function() {
                    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#008B8B';
                }
                document.querySelector('#green').onclick = function() {
                    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#99ff99';
               }
                document.querySelector('#slate_gray').onclick = function() {
                    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#708090';
                }
    
                document.querySelector('#reset').onclick = function() {
                    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#F8F8FF';
                }
            </script>


The CSS code:
```

Comment: I what way is any of this related to C?

Comment: CSS has nothing to do with the C language apart from having the letter in the name :-)

Comment: You probably mean Adobe CS5. ?

Comment: CS50 has its on section on overflow. This question would be more relevant there.

Comment: Thnaks for all your help. New to stack overflow. Sorry for the incorrect tags. I ve updated it to the correct ones now

Comment: Feels like you are asking for someone to do your homework. Good that you included code, but you have not directed the reader as to which line(s) to look at. And tell us what you have tried and how it has worked or not worked. You may find someone that will help you, but many will not put much effort into an answer since you didn't put much effort into the question.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix would be to create a `.current` class. Then apply the current class to the link of the page that you are on.. Something like

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    /* Style the header */
    .header {
      background-color: #6699cc;
      padding: 20px;
      color: #e6e6e6;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Style the top navigation bar */
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      color: #993333;
    }
    
    .topnav .current {
      background:gray;
      color: black;
    }
    
    /* When the nav bar is selected */
    .topnav
     {
      color: white;
      background-color: chartreuse;
    }
    .nav-item > a:hover {
      color: aqua;
    }
    
    
    /* Style the topnav links */
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    /* Change color on hover */
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <title>Page 1</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
    
    
    <style></style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="page1.html"  class="current">Page 1</a>
      <a href="#">Page 2</a>
      <a href="#">Page 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    
    
    
       </style>
        </head>
        <body>
     <p>Select what background you'd like to use here!</p>
         <button id="aqua">Dark Cyan</button>
            <button id="green">Green</button>
            <button id="slate_gray">Slate Gray</button>
            <button id="reset">Reset</button>
            <script>
                document.querySelector('#aqua').onclick = function() {
                    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#008B8B';
                }
                document.querySelector('#green').onclick = function() {
                    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#99ff99';
               }
                document.querySelector('#slate_gray').onclick = function() {
                    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#708090';
                }
    
                document.querySelector('#reset').onclick = function() {
                    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#F8F8FF';
                }
            </script>


The CSS code:
```

**HTML - HOME PAGE  (index.html)**

```
<div class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Page 2</a>
    <a href="#">Page 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Then on the next page you add the class to the next link. So for page 2 it will look like this
**HTML - PAGE 2  (page2.html)**

```
<div class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="current">Page 2</a>
    <a href="#">Page 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Removed the current class from home link and added it to the second link. And on each page you add the class to the link of the page you are on.

Comment: Yet, I tried those changes but sadly it did not work